# How to GROUP BY DATETIME column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that tracks when a user scans a logo.  It tracks the DATETIME of the scan and also the points awarded to the user for the scan (between 1 and 5)

I am trying to calculate the average points awarded per day for the given week.  The challenge I have is when I use GROUP BY I'm getting back every scan because DATETIME value is by the second which can't be grouped.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Beginning of week is Monday
SELECT SUM(Points) AS Points, DateTime
FROM SmartTappScanLog
WHERE DateTime >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
  AND DateTime <  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
GROUP BY DATETIME
```

I've tried several things including:

```
GROUP BY CAST(DATETIME As DATE)
```

Comment: `GROUP BY CAST(DATETIME As DATE)` should works. What is your issue with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DATEPART()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql), like:

```
SELECT SUM(Points) AS Points, MIN(DateTime) as  DateTime
FROM SmartTappScanLog
WHERE DateTime >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
  AND DateTime <  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
GROUP BY DATEPART(day,DATETIME)
```